# Issues clearing tkinter canvas

Tags: python-3.x, canvas, tkinter

I wrote a program to draw some plots. I want to clear the screen and reuse the same canvas to draw different plot. How should i go about it? ocanvas is my outer canvas to which i'm attaching a scrollbar. innerCanvas is the canvas I do my drawing on. The first time I press "Go" I call the function drawGraph. I want the innerCanvas to be cleared the next time I press "Go" and then call drawGraph2.  Is there a way to accomplish this?. Below is my code:

(I'm a beginner in Python and thus I don't know all the concepts/functions present.)

```
from tkinter import *
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

def on_configure(event=None):
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))    

def drawGraph(innerCanvas):

    for i in range(5):
        f = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
        a = f.add_subplot(111)
        a.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18],[5,6,1,3,8,9,3,5,9,7,6,5,7,3,2,9,3,5])

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, innerCanvas)
        canvas.draw()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)


def drawGraph2(innerCanvas):

    for i in range(5):
        f = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
        a = f.add_subplot(111)
        a.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14],[3,4,5,6,8,9,0,1,23,44,4,5,17,5])

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, innerCanvas)
        canvas.draw()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)

root=Tk()
ocanvas=Canvas(root)
innerCanvas=Canvas(canvas)

xscrollbar=Scrollbar(ocanvas, orient=HORIZONTAL)
xscrollbar.config(command=ocanvas.xview)

button=Button(root, text='Go',command= lambda: drawGraph(frame))
button.pack()

ocanvas.configure(scrollregion=ocanvas.bbox("all"))
ocanvas.config(xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set)


xscrollbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

ocanvas.bind("<Configure>", on_configure)
ocanvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
ocanvas.create_window((0,0),window=innerCanvas, anchor='nw')
root.geometry('500x500')
root.mainloop()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clear `innerCanvas` You can destroy its children before calling `drawGraph2`.

```
for figureCanvas in innerCanvas.winfo_children():
    figureCanvas.destroy()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Your suggestion works. Thank you. Much appreciated.